# QuickSI algorithm for finding subgraph isomorphisms

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, subgraph, isomorphism

I am studying the Quick Subgraph Isomorphism (QuickSI) Algorithm and I am having a problem understanding the formulae regarding the inner support and average inner support calculation described at page 6, (2) and (3). If "v" stands for vertex and "e" stands for edge, then what does f(v) and f(e) do? How can I obtain the values of Table 2 from page 6? Definition 4 from page 5 does not really do much good in helping me understand. By isomorphic mappings from the query graph to the data graph I understand taking different components from the query graph and see if they can be found in the data graph. But the computation time for this does not seem to be too feasible for large graphs.

Here you can find the original article:
http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lxue/10papers/vldb08_haichuan.pdf

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The function *f* is described in Definition 1 - it's just the isomorphism function that preserved the labels (*l*).

The 'average inner-support' is the number of 'features' (for example, vertices) that have an isomorphism divided by the number of graphs that have an isomorphism. To get the values of the table, you would need to know the dataset of graphs (*D*) that was used. It doesn't seem to be referenced except in Example 4.

Really, taking a step back - do you need to implement this particular algorithm? There are plenty of simpler ones that might be slightly slower, but clearer. Furthermore, why not use someone else's implementation of a subgraph isomorphism algorithm?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Yes I have to implement this. The dataset of graphs (D) is located at page 1, Figure 2. I have been trying to use the two formulas but I could not get the answers from Table 2. If posible, can you help me with a step by step example of using the formulas with the datasets? I could not obtain 1.4 nor 5.1 for edge type N-C, nor edge type C-C. Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm. Weird I tried to calculate it as well, and the values don't seem to match. For example, phi-avg(N) should be 4/3, right? There are 4 vertices in D that are labelled as 'N' and there are 3 graphs that contain an f(v) - that is, 3 that have (at least one?) mapping. Maybe the table doesn't actually correspond to the D they give? You could always ask the authors...

Comment: I worked on the part with the edges. We have 4 mappings for the NC edge over the three data graphs. I tried the following: 1) 4/3, four mappings over 3 graphs. Did not work. 2) 4/20, where 20 is the total number of edges in the three graphs. No success. 3) 4/16. 16 edges because I subtracted the 4 appearances of NC from the total of 20 edges. The last resort that I will attempt will be to count the total number of features that contain this edge and could be mapped. If this fails, I will finally contact the authors.